# Spring Framework: how to pass a classes methods to another class' second method?

Tags: java, spring

I have this class with a method in it (randomizer)

```
public class WebDriverCustomMethods {

        public int randomizer(int min, int max) {
            int d = (max - min) + 1;
            int c = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((d)));
            return c;
        }
```

that I want to use in my test class like so:

```
public class AppTest3 { 

    public static DataProviderClass appdata;
    public static WebDriverCustomMethods w;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        appdata = (DataProviderClass) context.getBean("data");  
        w = (WebDriverCustomMethods) context.getBean("wdcm");
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="standardTestData", dataProviderClass=DataProviderClass.class)
    public void oneUserTwoUser(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array) throws Exception {

            int randomNumber = w.randomizer(1, 99999);
```

when I run this and when the code gets to using w.randomizer(1,9999) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.f1rstt.tests.AppTest3.oneUserTwoUser(AppTest3.java:34) //this is int randomNumber = w.randomizer(1, 99999);
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

This is my spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans SYSTEM "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd" PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN">
<beans>
    <bean id="data" class="com.blah.tests.DataProviderClass"/>
    <bean id="wdcm" class="com.blah.tests.WebDriverCustomMethods"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestNG doesn't care about your main method. It will thus never be called when executing the tests, and the fields will thus never be executed.

Read the [introduction of the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#introduction) of TestNG, which explains the @BeforeXxx annotations.

That said, I don't know why you're using Spring in these tests, instead of just creating new instances of your 2 classes by yourself.

Comment: someone told me extending classes in order to get their methods is not a good practice (I had a long chain of inheritance) and they recommended that I use dependency injection. when I started learning dependency injection, I was told to learn using Spring...

Comment: I cant test this now because I am having another problem elsewhere in the code, but as soon as I do test this I will let you know what happened

Comment: You're not using dependency injection here, but dependency lookup. You're loading a bean from a spring context. Using `new WebDriverCustomMethods()` would have the same effect, but would be simpler and faster.

Comment: Im confused about why should I use DI at all... it was so much easier when I had the chain of extended classes...

Comment: Extending a class must be done when you have a is-a relationship: a Banana is-a Fruit. Whan you have a use-a or has-a realationship, you use composition: Carpenter has-a hammer.

Comment: in my code I have some methods that I use like 30-40 times in a class. Much nicer to just use the method by typing its name, then by typing classname.methodname... this really bothers me with composition.

Comment: It seems like you want your OO code to look like procedural code. This is a bad idea.